# How to load assets using ResourceManager in overlap2d?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/09/08/Guest-Tutorial-Making-Flappy-Bird-using-Overlap2D-and-LibGDX.aspx) to get started with Overlap2D.

Sadly they have switched from `DefaultAssetManager` to `ResourceManager` without updating the tutorial.

This is the code that uses  `DefaultAssetManager`.

```
    // Initializing asset manager
    assetManager = new ResourceManager();

    // providing the list of sprite animations which is one in this case, to avoid directory listing coding
    assetManager.spriteAnimationNames = new String[1];
    assetManager.spriteAnimationNames[0] = "bird";

    // loading assets into memory
    assetManager.loadData();
```

Does anybody has a more up to date tutorial or know how to fix this error?

Comment: assetManager.initAllResources(); will load the texture. 

assetManager.spriteAnimationNames is not needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this new tutorial: http://overlap2d.com/quick-start-setting-up-runtime-video/

It should answer all your questions.

But in short, the easiest way is to either use empty constructor for scene loader and forget about resource manager letting it do it all for you, or use initAllResources on rm (as it was mentioned in comments), to let it load all.